# How to get 'species score' for ordination with metaMDS()?

Tags: r, vegan

I am using `metaMDS()` from Vegan to make an ordination. My data is samples (rows) times variables (columns). In my case the columns are analytes measured i blood, i.e. not 'species' per se. Due to the different scales for my variables I have transformed the data using `scale(center = T, scale = T)`. 
It is a numeric matrix with no missing values and no binary variables. 
But the function does not calculate scores for 'species' (i.e. my analytes).
And I get the message 'species scores not available'. 
I can't find anywhere that these scores should not be calculated when using 'euclidean' distance. I normally get the species score when I use Bray-Curtis distance on a regular community dataset.

```
plotdf <- structure(c(-0.698904932895234, 0.30704395903274, 1.24113935868014, 
2.30332141847988, -0.723897451949346, 0.122724131008669, 0.160212909589836, 
0.0446225089645731, 0.39451777572213, -0.105332605360096, -0.892596955564596, 
0.338284607850377, 0.178957298880421, 0.15396477982631, 1.61602714449181, 
-0.292776498265928, -0.814495333520497, -0.533329494161748, -0.336513406610622, 
-0.211550811340068, 3.13524832588293, 2.26119814124526, 1.70180602307717, 
1.80669204523371, 3.13524832588293, 1.87661606000469, 1.52699598614965, 
2.12135011170326, -1.06718496185488, -1.13361277588734, -0.601897693913475, 
-0.328503392807931, 1.46276186573425, 0.00347540139166063, -0.745695995144315, 
-0.749246570483348, -0.76344887183948, -0.775875885526096, -0.807831063577394, 
0.0869139218589377, -0.832685090950625, -0.0923901327622313, 
-0.587695392557344, -0.770550022517546, -0.0107268999644709, 
-0.525560324124265, -0.427919502300856, -0.798954625229811, -0.806055775907877, 
-0.310750516112765, 3.44444636497001, 0.200147425204428, -0.0244578860101126, 
0.200147425204428, -0.36968456806209, -0.398800071367679, -0.120123111157047, 
0.408115305958629, -0.890990722485962, -0.961699801942393, -0.273778277609555, 
0.41093290575329, 3.181624670989, 3.76548692036815, -0.406474243377552, 
0.416240744384011, 0.00222933118786958, -0.427705597900429, -0.268470438978834, 
-1.12834029715544, -0.517938854622665, -0.783330786158653, -0.661250497652098, 
-0.862948365619448, 0.947024607455987, -0.204776375410201, -0.581632918191303, 
-0.348088018439634, 0.368470196707535, -0.188852859518039, 0.865085267987317, 
0.286121529607417, 0.570778700977531, 0.382615486004067, 0.821662987608825, 
0.44533655766189, 1.25106109357391, 2.8818089566773, -1.44594498771245, 
-1.13716432724317, -1.44345540764024, 0.543632464272209, -0.889117589295565, 
0.151331854366745, 0.765367591610085, 0.577745560785727, 0.245142869778918, 
-1.26436165094427, -0.326251496822513, -1.02556997534963, -0.974400330579358, 
-0.778250025626633, 0.466877997116795, -0.539458350031998, -1.07673962011992, 
0.867706881150637, 0.0745773872113305, -0.104516369484636, -1.57990779369432, 
-0.360364593336031, 0.485255827280768, 3.57337992412814, 0.256505894180964, 
-0.264535620101922, 2.13733867744602, 1.79421377779631, 1.52733885584654, 
2.07379702936274, -1.15411869326783, 1.20963061543015, -0.278018853200573, 
0.884992040049025, 2.17533989241356, 1.52167683562364, 0.137948546574831, 
-0.278018853200573, 0.154926807790159, -0.176149285908647, -0.575138424468722, 
-0.69398625297599, -0.278018853200573, -0.626073208114692, -0.626073208114692, 
-0.736431906014289, 0.307731158728054, -0.294997114415901, -0.855279734521558, 
-0.311975375631229, -0.430823204138483, -0.227084069554603, 2.88551074988959, 
2.47142262330214, 1.68465518278598, 2.11254624692636, 3.60326350264118, 
3.56185468998243, 2.47142262330214, 2.73367843680753, -0.675647138762483, 
-0.38578545015127, -0.294373188387428, 2.29466328872395, 6.49068792404239, 
2.82139829613626, -0.0622526766464104, 0.535904026686221, 0.0180967312639449, 
-0.705047939929233, -0.642553955998955, -0.142602084556756, -0.0711803886364486, 
-0.633626244008917, -0.937168451670251, 0.160940123104569, -0.294373188387428, 
0.321638938925279, -1.08001184351088, -0.749686499879426, -0.517565988138408, 
-0.553276836098561, 0.54926502031515, 1.38672720907941, -0.444646148767711, 
-0.987616139285201, -0.407834623986865, -0.49066055474377, -0.923195970918719, 
-0.38022598040123, -0.242182762473055, 0.107526722944989, -1.46680807598847, 
2.62643635730582, 1.68823363847608, -1.17998610194623, -0.992345558180284, 
-0.831510806380897, -2.25489835980544, -0.724287638514648, -1.45876633839851, 
-0.295394967049624, 0.428361416047591, -0.375812342949318, 0.669613543746671, 
1.17892359111139, 2.46560160550643, 0.750030919646365, -1.77775526280061, 
-0.751093430481203, -0.456229718849011, 0.696419335713228, 0.378429058462806, 
0.84201157835516, 0.713238656162837, -0.832036410144966, 0.919275331670544, 
-0.162417214744905, 0.0178648763243318, 0.172392382955099, -0.342699305814142, 
-0.445717643567996, -1.1097816715345, 0.730197996765378, 6.53377023116585, 
1.26110122121555, -0.855239029674838, 0.104750362481623, 0.221112713046046, 
-0.484334037250749, -0.549787859443237, -1.13887225917561, -0.54251521253296, 
-0.498879331071302, -0.964328733328984, 0.301111829059086, 0.337475063610461, 
0.0902050686610707, -1.16069019990644, -1.21305325766043, -0.0261572819033443, 
-0.797057854392627, -0.140787338747868, 0.441771092401777, -0.470669823856697, 
-0.751420875013156, -1.16552867546893, -1.00409682105396, -0.582970244319283, 
-0.681233112224038, -0.877758848033557, -0.639120454550571, -0.167969655559799, 
2.19329729357675, 5.38160698124336, 4.37477234303285, -0.359747681885611, 
0.982698502395062, 0.587156323098077, -0.371733808530972, -0.395706061821705, 
-1.59911317701617, -0.563511834856784, -0.851178874345507, -0.659400848019695, 
-0.347761555240249, -0.155983528914438, 1.30632392181987, -0.87515112763623, 
-0.44365056840315, -0.155983528914438, -0.503581201629967, -0.0537715590349406, 
2.47365169616714, 0.150652380724054, 0.531624268456718, 0.420120301315449, 
-0.193151517961524, 0.410828304053678, 1.05197611511598, -0.416159452244061, 
-0.769255348191411, -0.309794112249109, -0.304271920832414, -0.297815438433252, 
-0.297131810885106, -0.309361148135283, -0.307667270988209, -0.308829437820058, 
-0.30965738673948, -0.310135926023183, 0.243389703849444, -0.0870302777547278, 
-0.307849571667715, -0.309581428123019, -0.308821841958412, -0.307089985503107, 
0.0481760595453695, -0.149316343252526, -0.108298690363732, -0.211602408750324, 
-0.309323168827053, 1.63254216944839, 0.17253410335763, 0.235865204597817, 
-0.283223643067293, -0.304586580610635, -0.306690077901827, -0.306576986649612, 
-0.304925854367279, 0.0662283262758862, -0.301442643799068, 0.929605567553241, 
2.25902865198899, 4.95029977413941, 2.64812809133604, -0.47547574119999, 
-0.432242470161435, -0.302542657045751, -0.464667423440349, -0.464667423440349, 
-0.399817516882512, -0.670025460873512, 0.270298184215185, 0.270298184215185, 
1.19981351154425, 1.17819687602497, 0.194639959897707, -1.28609957317301, 
-0.637600507594599, 0.389189679571229, -0.432242470161435, -0.350014484068485, 
0.215408884220155, -0.423765358193087, -0.890854227648913, -0.841686978232511, 
-0.534391669379991, -0.645017980566895, -0.595850731150493, -0.80481154117021, 
-0.0918864246323654, -0.48374453836672, 4.17862597661995, 5.68911318449899, 
3.32268322548848, -0.257171457184862, 0.563526592429426, -0.513954282524298, 
-0.77073710786374, -0.977170359607208, -0.443464879489945, -1.01241506112439, 
0.0701007711889329, -0.322625902859619, -0.0708780348797788, 
0.910938650241606, -0.221926755667683, -0.513954282524298, -0.322625902859619, 
0.03989102703135, 0.0902406006273229, -0.0648244445283561, 0.391240413183369, 
0.285285951290747, -0.253699789641292, -0.659090774273934, -0.742011657494247, 
-0.566956459584699, -0.461001997692076, -0.682124352946243, -0.258306505375753, 
-0.420693217666615, 2.40995896415691, 6.42553531511589, 1.48835127705159, 
0.161894498824987, 0.665487270707522, 0.994632873245161, 0.105939746393572, 
-0.23308022422017, -1.90513988511128, -0.697175523798217, 0.33634166816991, 
0.764230951468825, 0.402170788677427, 0.145437218698094, 0.402170788677427, 
-0.279160608575437, -0.256120416397798, -0.341698273057587, 0.435085348931185, 
0.838074051864222, 1.31633692302975, 0.59894261628146, 0.412951499717062, 
0.0409692665883208, -0.657825928503537, 0.333241021189475, 0.120679745115908, 
-0.362897157951458, -0.171592009485246, -0.333650770025627, 2.21948894199296, 
5.12305959487686, 1.43519112196112, -0.150091705762848, 0.634206114269011, 
0.433959862345984, -0.450461083647381, -0.617332960249911, -1.13463577771773, 
-0.68408171089092, 1.18488330705733, 0.70095486491002, 0.667580489589508, 
0.1502776721217, 0.433959862345984, 9.29831794179632e-05, -0.0332813921410786, 
0.116903296801188, 0.484021425326744, 0.807251285728501, 1.62776898417899, 
0.652436625643507, 1.10139913989, -0.245488402849498, -0.601562121044994, 
0.265399975431007, -0.322895732891995, -0.245488402849498, -0.183562538815489, 
-0.171864707173939, 2.88790201225057, 6.25364540361752, 2.77316076027215, 
-0.22923533316314, 0.382718010721768, 0.382718010721768, -0.611706173091208, 
-0.66907679908041, -1.18541243298329, -0.860312219044444, -0.496964921112788, 
-0.22923533316314, 0.172359048761322, 0.688694682664205, 0.191482590757734, 
-0.649953257084015, -0.343976585141561, -0.210111791166746, 0.975547812610265, 
0.222389325297373, 0.851437956724518, 0.303036585736753, -0.713118895799399, 
-0.632471635360019, -1.26152026678716, -0.616342183272147, -0.584083279096402, 
-1.03570793755692, -0.245364785251013, 0.00895755191294446, 0.984545704690042, 
7.5829220077053, 2.82642375246424, -0.248095758051148, 0.559496924434463, 
1.77392201087898, 0.377333161467775, 0.680939433078909, -1.05366439872601, 
-0.826971715923037, -0.235951507186702, -0.00521074076224157, 
-0.110460914920767, -0.0477156187878014, 0.336852325252967, -0.493004817150792, 
-0.177254294675216, -0.316913179616336, -0.377634433938563, -0.422757412167952, 
0.295225804994338, -0.0721144456468375, -0.289179139207527, -0.416078498519931, 
-0.753363637745003, -0.514592474828243, -0.436115239463994, -0.850207885641312, 
-0.239087286847367, -0.00656190873037701, 2.43718215979915, 5.49186224546105, 
2.79088195919157, -0.199489072035347, 0.73299221727198, 1.05453748944691, 
0.379292417879529, 0.34713789066204, -0.476018006105799, -0.00656190873037701, 
-0.0708709631653894, 0.15421072735707, 0.73299221727198, 0.700837690054491, 
0.443601472314542, -0.919750481707214, 0.218519781792082, 1.1831555983169, 
-0.482448911549298, -0.344507148209773, 0.458909211725853, -0.116463203249896, 
-0.463791673265714, 0.0729886894860142, 0.318574476365909, -0.312931832753788, 
0.318574476365909, -1.04618082500943, -0.0322623620339359, -0.0384066209005535, 
1.53648495801046, 6.52705048079341, 3.16250938039262, 0.749039168554954, 
0.45246867642236, 0.697906325083822, -0.2429379947851, -0.263391132173553, 
-0.935276695384289, -0.3554302504216, -0.760402370712999, -0.723586723413778, 
0.186577890372456, -0.212258288702411, 1.35240672151437, -1.11321899066384, 
-1.02015721554638, -0.488375643446552, -0.212258288702411, -0.517689783976593, 
-0.517689783976593, -0.404074729996812, -0.716516128441214, -0.678644443781284, 
-1.01380885302165, -0.574497310966489, -0.12950501621233, -0.77332365543111, 
-0.527157705141571, -0.6329761214973, 2.18318173522514, 4.28249941023639, 
0.954312852291706, 0.391081280947224, 0.595892761436129, 1.00551572241394, 
0.365479845886108, 0.109465495274971, -0.376961770886163, -0.095345985213934, 
1.3383343782084, 1.49194298857507, 1.3383343782084, 0.672697066619453, 
-0.095345985213934, -1.62119151485626, -0.607374686436184, 0.467885586130548, 
1.38953724833063, -0.651224895277883, 0.155618947409365, -1.0668717233289, 
-1.18912079040272, -1.11577135015842, -0.82237358918124, -1.26247023064701, 
-0.895723029425547, -1.0668717233289, 0.0333698803355454, -0.052069378070287, 
2.73328153457067, 6.5440088820849, 2.54963202384708, -0.113285881644804, 
0.162188384440567, 0.529487405887713, -0.453037476483425, -0.296935392368385, 
-1.05295921151378, -0.624443686492099, -0.401003448445078, -0.312239518262021, 
1.41712670771834, 0.238709013908721, 1.26408544878204, -0.928995791775366, 
-0.945830330258361, -0.251023014687489, 0.0397553772915032, -0.592177487733025, 
-0.00842427829955308, -0.251023014687489, -0.607339908757271, 
-0.856003613554907, -1.00459533959252, -0.763512845307005, -0.53456028784089, 
-0.402647224929949, -0.251023014687489, 0.227980242429395, 2.40547844522623, 
3.95993525473729, 3.4564674621831, 1.24750252235161, 1.12792892161999, 
1.00206197348145, 0.668514560914304, 0.580407697217322, -0.0363403486615505, 
-0.137033907172389, 0.523767570554978, 0.731448034983579, -0.181087339020876, 
-0.470581319739529, -0.653088394540424, -0.395061150856403, 0.0580598624423623, 
0.397900622416433, 0.888781720156762, -0.584336071479825, -0.50609378010719, 
-0.40377693754298, -0.295441457180876, -1.1861998512693, -1.37277762300404, 
-0.993603441736668, -0.722764740831404, 0.420776440768595, 0.637447401492804, 
-0.272315269292895, 2.66941297149803, 7.41532733360265, 3.99900765660126, 
0.157956344080792, 0.361088865416019, 1.2474853221515, 0.638087758145851, 
0.619621165297205, -0.807846461903923, -0.111655911509586, -0.407121397088085, 
-0.259388654298836, -0.0673360886728128, -0.364648233536176, 
-0.146742437922033, -0.67858031196333, -0.370188211390772, -0.120889207933915, 
0.342622272567355, -0.0607210092437259, 0.0586382429485912, -0.0802880997670564, 
-0.246608369215364, -0.248565078267698, -0.589032453373648, -0.305309640785355, 
-0.117465571761385, -0.497067127913995, -0.178123552383708, 0.0562843265198969, 
1.72321561241497, 4.55261213715794, 1.83288214438177, 0.297550696846829, 
0.385283922420244, 0.9555498886475, -0.47011502692064, -0.711381397247572, 
-0.996514380361199, 0.385283922420244, 0.911683275860804, 0.385283922420244, 
0.802016743894006, 0.363350616026884, 0.626550292747176, 0.122084245699975, 
0.780083437500669, 0.451083841600322, 0.9555498886475, 0.318768231003561, 
0.715510556440497, 0.219582649644338, 0.358442463547259, -0.157322559520749, 
-0.593739117501383, 0.219582649644338, 0.0608857194695682, -0.375530838511066, 
-0.196996792064447, -0.652950143413879, 0.625186447640068, 1.98637884605493, 
2.40165788285948, -0.832904392695844, -0.558358807252847, -0.648335931893829, 
-0.846747027255997, -0.922881517336828, -0.703706470134434, -0.969023632537331, 
-0.309191385170126, -0.496066951732166, -0.323034019730277, 0.902039138843094, 
-0.043874222767227, -0.355333500370629, -0.0392600112471769, 
-0.392247192531032, -1.17897025669963, 2.3237306833112, 3.55022035107835, 
1.63689646936162, 1.85766460955969, 3.82004807798711, 3.30492241752492, 
1.6859560560723, 1.53877729594025, 0.255869103455813, -0.217555908302303, 
0.147043929627318, 1.33013687809435, 1.4455605803838, 2.80178908228503, 
-0.689777911971317, 1.73411983610745, 0.810730217791754, -0.545498284109474, 
0.0316202273378633, -0.834057539833125, -0.776345688688416, 0.724162441074655, 
-0.920625316550224, -0.89176939097787, -0.603210135254218, -0.862913465405515, 
0.233611706344417, 0.781874292219364, -0.0838034749516248, -0.603210135254218, 
-0.630192299425754, 0.643965453120263, -0.855043667522133, -0.292915247281239, 
-1.07989503561849, -1.37969685974697, -0.855043667522133, -1.11737026363455, 
0.344163628991805, -0.705142755457904, -0.421112829288472, 1.33922283110583, 
5.51499186229142, 4.4040074411503, -0.559028136740472, -0.622239319322639, 
-0.421112829288472, -0.250634185354747, -0.354070665943748, -0.817619338212975, 
-0.854013655457253, -0.664380107710751, -0.662464617329474, -0.281282031455192, 
0.0194499584054227, 0.0941540832752574, -0.827196790119363, -0.817619338212975, 
-0.409619887000803, -0.597337944366027, -0.0832549257485097, 
0.204960720543472, -0.143804431272036, -0.170446213702386, -0.158336312597682, 
-0.20435393679556, 0.277620127171702, 0.476222505288867, -0.642732356785886, 
-0.591870772146124, -1.49887064253455, -1.22501683268422, -1.6774709533065, 
-0.955131918628824, -0.133570489077839, 1.93025532428696, 0.945969167143749, 
0.473670567546803, 0.362541485288701, 1.69212157659102, -0.645558046624104, 
2.56527865147613, 1.53336574479373, 1.1483828526853, 2.48590073557747, 
0.0251853427194558, 0.807057814321117, 0.830871189090712, 1.49367678684442, 
-0.0740370521538533, 0.951792873536318, 2.5032023290554, 0.318564524344853, 
0.635178698940584, -0.241842564689589, 0.125429877841457, -0.685102409123612, 
0.375555075772084, 0.188752712760605, 0.217247988474217, -0.423761492139935, 
0.962684741533591, 4.03514176906493, 4.24637318970771, -0.813579477507975, 
-0.264377783836745, -0.441044062919797, -0.723326052324239, -0.560101772736638, 
-1.00752832737089, -0.974883471453369, -0.500572917828217, -0.638833484067129, 
-0.661876911773614, 0.482613330981802, 0.232976197494883, -0.437203491635383, 
-0.375754351084758, -0.421841206497728, -0.88847061755405, 1.20779505745642, 
4.21167561465542, 0.750682798752242, 1.07719155496952, 2.10025232445032, 
2.1437868252793, 1.42546756160128, 0.990122553311588, -0.270201245687125, 
-0.668541928272209, -0.587206054192632, 0.227535614993705, -0.34580111517447, 
-1.10019154960626, 1.34403345795275, 1.8268433359891, 1.25350660582093, 
1.19315537106641, 0.468940554011867, 0.921574814670944, 3.21492173534361, 
0.287886849748252, -0.0742205587790054, -0.315625497797195, 1.58543839697094, 
0.378413701880074, -0.858786610588067, -0.526854819438082, 1.10262851893459, 
-0.466503584683535, 0.913870401723578, 1.69394221264665, -0.126225346173866, 
-0.357357734595538, -1.05075489986049, -0.126225346173866, -0.241791540384716, 
0.0760154936950757, -0.299574637490112, 0.0471239451423484, -0.0968113092559779, 
0.902046474926439, -1.32907915984528, -1.42862168816586, 0.558796377269263, 
-0.405736397147445, 1.27962158234934, -0.203218839529706, -0.347383880545724, 
2.03477179719514, 1.34827160188079, 2.03477179719514, 2.03477179719514, 
1.00502150422358, 1.86314674836655, 0.0130287219943229, 0.0679487376194715, 
1.0393465139893, 0.593121387034955, 0.370008823557797, 1.09287313812892, 
2.98712089240292, 0.0437513049925516, 0.364316309562003, 0.0728935781352272, 
-0.13110233386351, 0.422600855847354, -0.166073061634724, 0.393458582704678, 
0.422600855847354), .Dim = c(30L, 30L), .Dimnames = list(c("2", 
"7", "10", "11", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "28", "29", "32", 
"33", "35", "37", "39", "42", "43", "44", "46", "61", "62", "63", 
"64", "66", "67", "68", "69", "71", "72"), c("C0_S", "C2_S", 
"C3_S", "C12.DC_S", "C12.1_S", "Ala_S", "Arg_S", "Asn_S", "Cit_S", 
"Gln_S", "Gly_S", "His_S", "Ile_S", "Leu_S", "Lys_S", "Orn_S", 
"Phe_S", "Pro_S", "Ser_S", "Thr_S", "Trp_S", "Tyr_S", "Val_S", 
"Creatinine_S", "Spermidine_S", "t4.OH.Pro_S", "Taurine_S", "total.DMA_S", 
"lysoPC.a.C14.0_S", "lysoPC.a.C16.0_S")))
```

I have tried these to version:

```
NMDS=metaMDS(plotdf,k=2,trymax=500, distance = "euclidean")
NMDS=metaMDS(daisy(plotdf, metric ="euclidean", stand = F ))
```

And I get this message:

```
plot(NMDS)
species scores not available
```

Is there something I haven't understood for this function, e.g. the negative values when scaling or the choice of distance.. which is causing this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`metaMDS` finds species scores after the analysis using weighted averages, and these are not well-defined for negative input (as these would imply negative weights). However, if you have used scaled data and Euclidean distances, you can find species scores similarly as in PCA: as fitted vectors. In **vegan** this would go like this with your example:

```
NMDS=metaMDS(plotdf,k=2,trymax=500, distance = "euclidean")
envfit(NMDS, plotdf) # species scores
```